**404 Error with `drf_with_firebase_auth` Signup Endpoint**
I'm following the tutorial from the GitHub repository [https://github.com/Abiorh001/drf_with_firebase_auth] and have completed the setup steps. However, I'm encountering a 404 error (Not Found) when trying to send a signup request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/auth/sign-up/ using Postman.
I've checked the urls.py file and the URL pattern seems to be defined correctly. I've also set the environment variables for Firebase credentials as instructed in the tutorial.
There are no error messages in the console.
this is the result when i try to send request in postman
For reference, this is urls.py from accounts app:
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/sign-up/', AuthCreateNewUserView.as_view(), name='auth-create-user'),
    path('auth/sign-in/', AuthLoginExisitingUserView.as_view(), name='auth-login-drive-user'),
    path('<str:pk>/', RetrieveUpdateDestroyExistingUser.as_view(), name='retrieve-update-user'),
    path('auth/update-email-address/', UpdateUserEmailAddressView.as_view(), name='user-update-email-address'),
    path('auth/reset-password/', UserPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='user-reset-password'),
]


and this is my main projects urls.py
api_version = 'v1'

urlpatterns = [
    path(f'api/{api_version}/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(f'api/{api_version}/users/', include('accounts.urls')),
    re_path(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    path(f'api/{api_version}/swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path(f'api/{api_version}/redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]

What could be causing the 404 error when trying to sign up
Thanks in advance for any help!
I have looked for solution all over the internet but i found nothing that could help me.

It may not be entirely accurate, but please have a look at the "trailing slash" issue.
